# When should you use RocksDB or LevelDB

Tags: embedded-database, leveldb, rocksdb

In the scenario where you've stored ~1TB of key/value, and need to provide a production API to 1000s of users.

Further, the store will only be used for read operations only (after 1-time initial write)

Comment: In my experience leveldb is faster, rocksdb is more reliable (leveldb may get corrupted after power loss).

Comment: It depends on the workload...

Answer (score 0):

You should use rocksdb and also hold the data in your ram, as much as possible, and serve responses from there (the more the better)